# Decompress stream from HttpClient using SharpZipLib in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, httpclient, sharpziplib

I am trying decompress stream from HttpClient using SharpZipLib in Xamarin.Forms. This code perfectly works on iOS, but on Android CanDecompressEntry() always returns false. What i'm missing? Maybe Android need some permissions?

```
                var zipStream = await httpClient.GetStreamAsync(url);

                using (ZipInputStream s = new ZipInputStream(zipStream))
                {
                    ZipEntry theEntry;
                    //const int size = 2048;
                    byte[] data = new byte[2048];

                    Debug.WriteLine(s.CanDecompressEntry);

                    while ((theEntry = s.GetNextEntry()) != null)
                    {
                        if (theEntry.IsFile)
                        {
                            string str = "";
                            while (true)
                            {
                                int size = s.Read(data, 0, data.Length);

                                if (size > 0)
                                {
                                    str += new UTF8Encoding().GetString(data, 0, size);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    files.Add(theEntry.Name.Substring(0,theEntry.Name.Length-5), str);
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                return files;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I just set ConfigureAwait to false, and it works.

```
var zipStream = await httpClient.GetStreamAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false);
```